# I need a regex that can detect if a string has code AND a comment

Tags: java, regex

I have to build a code analyzer that takes java files as input, looks at it line by line and detects if a line has java code and a java comment.

Some examples:

```
int i++; //this increments i

String yolo = "swag"; /* block comment */

String swag = "yolo"; /* multiline 
block comment */

int jim = 46; /** Javadoc */

int funny = 69; /** Multiline 
Javadoc */

/* Another comment */ int j = 8;

/** JavaDoc comment */ int k = 2;
```

The regex should be able to detect any of these patterns, my approach was to divide and conquer since I am not a regex god, I figured i could make a different regex to check for the examples that have comments after the code and another one that checks to see if there are comments before the code.

This only has to work with java code and any comment writable in java.

This is what I have so far just for the one that checks to see if there is code followed by any type of comment

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[*&&[^//]&&[^/\\* * \\*/]&&[^/\\*\\* * \\*/]][[//*]&&[&[^/\\\\* * \\\\*/]&&[^/\\\\*\\\\* * \\\\*/]]]");
```

The way I see this regex logically is that it will match against any string that starts with anything Except a // comment or /* */ comment or a JavaDoc comment followed by any one of those types of comments.

This, unfortunately, did not match on any of the examples I gave it

Is there something off with the regex or maybe a simpler way to approach this problem or approach building this regex?

Comment: To be honest I'd just do plain old iterative/index checks for `//` (until end of line) or `/*` (until the next occurrence of `*/`), with everything in between being a captured comment. Seems like less work to me. But I didn't see you post what the actual problem is, just the solution for it (are you trying to grab the comments?)

Comment: Hey @Rogue Thanks for the comment, I did not think of that but it actually seems like a simpler way to attack the problem, I might try it out next, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This use case could use a multiline regex ont the entire text, but in general is not suited.

For instance also considering a string literal `"//"` would make it really unwise (need to find pairs). And with the latest java there are multi line literals.

Regex on the entire text of multiple lines using `(?s)` to interprete `.` also as wildcard for line breaks:

```
Pattern comment = Pattern.compile("(?s)(/\\*.*?\\*/|//.*?\\R)"); // Or
Pattern comment = Pattern.compile("(/\\*.*?\\*/|//.*?\\R)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
                                    ----------- --------
                                    /* ...   */ // ...
comment.matcher(text). ...
```

Coded out is simpler. Here for returning only the real code lines:

```
Stream<String> uncommentedLines(Stream<String> lines) {
    AtomicBoolean insideBlockComment = new AtomicBoolean();
    return lines.flatMap(line -> {
        if (insideBlockComment.get()) {
            int p = line.indexOf("*/");
            if (p != -1) {
                insideBlockComment.set(false);
                return line.substring(p + 2);
            }
            return Stream.empty();
        } else {
            int p = line.indexOf("//");
            if (p != -1) {
                line = line.substring(0, p);
            }
            p = line.indexOf("/*");
            if (p != -1) {
                insideBlockComment.set(true);
                line = line.substring(0, p);
            }
            return Stream.of(line);
        }
    });
}
```

One usage for regex is to undo u-escaping of say `\u002F` (`'/'`):

```
// Java >= 9
text = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\u([0-9A-Fa-F]{4})").matcher(text)
    .replaceAll(mR -> Character.toString((char)Integer.parseInt(mR.group(1), 16)));
```

Comment: Thank you Joop Eggen this solves my problem exactly, thank you kindly for your answer I really appreciate it :)